# How to replace elemets in second column of data frame if the element in first column match another element in another data.frame?

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, match

I want to replace characters in second column of a data.frame if their first column matches in another data.frame. So the files are like this:

File1:

```
        Genotype          Group Type
1  08ZB02005DH01  08ZB02005DH01 Line
2  08ZB07005DH04  08ZB07005DH04 Line
3  08ZB08B06DH02  08ZB08B06DH02 Line
4  08ZB13005DH04  08ZB13005DH04 Line
5  08ZB18B24DH01  08ZB18B24DH01 Line
6 JRP4RA6121-002 JRP4RA6121-002 Line
```

File2:

```
       Genotype      POL       RE       ZE
1 08ZB08B06DH02 102.6110 94.94690 97.33455
2 08ZB18B24DH01 102.3411 94.18070 96.29505
3 08ZB02005DH01 101.0357 95.59205 96.62890
4 08ZB13005DH04 101.9972 96.57825 98.62155
5 08ZB07005DH04 103.5134 92.92665 96.10605
```

This is the code that I use:

```
Group_code1 <- 'TS'                     
Group_code2 <- 'PS'
for (i in 1:dim(file1)[1]) {
    if ((match(file1[i,1],file2[,1], nomatch=0)) >= 1) {test[i,2]<-Group_code2} else { test[i,2]<-Group_code2}

  }
```

what I expect as output is:

```
        Genotype Group Type
1  08ZB02005DH01  TS Line
2  08ZB07005DH04  TS Line
3  08ZB08B06DH02  TS Line
4  08ZB13005DH04  TS Line
5  08ZB18B24DH01  TS Line
6 JRP4RA6121-002  PS Line
```

but I get this error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "PS") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I would like to keep this part of the code(or at least something similar):

```
Group_code1 <- 'TS'                     
Group_code2 <- 'PS'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: As the error message indicates, you have factor variables.  Change it to character.  `yourdata$yourcolumn <- as.character(yourdata$yourcolumn)`

Comment: I get for all the rows "PS" when I run the comand. The error is gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df1` is your first `data.frame` and `df2` is the second, you can try:

```
df1$Group<-c("PS","TS")[ (df1$Group %in% df2$Genotype) +1]
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table) 
setkey(setDT(df1), Group)[df2[,1, drop=FALSE],
            Group:='TS'][Group!='TS', Group:='PS'][]
#         Genotype Group Type
#1:  08ZB02005DH01    TS Line
#2:  08ZB07005DH04    TS Line
#3:  08ZB08B06DH02    TS Line
#4:  08ZB13005DH04    TS Line
#5:  08ZB18B24DH01    TS Line
#6: JRP4RA6121-002    PS Line
```